TF/IDF not considerend for score on a wildcard match
I have noticed, a match on a wildcard search with a custom boost, always adds the full boost to the score. If a match on dame^45, the score of 45 is added, from the score-debug:
45.0 = max of:
    45.0 = name_text_de:*damen*^45.0

If I have an exact match with the boost of 50, tf and idf are taken into consideration and I do end up with a lower score:
    40.704887 = weight(name_text_de:dam in 8683) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:
      40.704887 = score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:
        50.0 = boost
        1.5380976 = idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:
          3838 = n, number of documents containing term
          17870 = N, total number of documents with field
        0.5292887 = tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:
          1.0 = freq, occurrences of term within document
          1.2 = k1, term saturation parameter
          0.75 = b, length normalization parameter
          5.0 = dl, length of field
          7.635814 = avgdl, average length of field

I do understand for wildcard searches most of the filters are by-passed e.g. no stemming is applied, but why calculation for the score also differently which can lead to a partial match outscore an exact match despite of a lower boost?

Wildcard matches are scored as a constant: how would you define the score where multiple terms match? It would also require looking up the tf/idf for every possible matching token. See https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/WildcardQuery.html for a reference about wildcard queries using constant scoring.

thanks for your response!
I naively assumed that it will calculated it the same way, just when looking for the matching token it will apply a wildcards search on the tokens, but I see how it will cause issues if we have multiple terms matching.
keeping this in mind, we have to pay attention, giving the wild-card match a boost which is not too close to the boost of the exact match e.g. max 50% of it, since we do not  want the wildcard match to outscore the exact match.
thanks again!

An alternative is not apply any boost at all to wildcard queries, and either use a separate boost / boost query to score documents - or apply boosts to each exact term in the search query.

Using the NgramFilter rather than doing a wildcard search would also solve my issue, wouldn't it? With theem,  I would get an exact match on the ngram and the score is calculated as it is for any other exact match. Is this assumption correct?
Thanks again!

Yes, that should work - just be aware that score will be based on that specific generated token, and not the weight / value of the original token the token was generated from. So searching for bar would match both foobar and barfoo, and it'd be scored based on the occurence of bar inside that specific field compared to all tokens, not whether foobar or barfoo was more "important" across the index for that specific document.
